# how to change reference voltage in an analog to digital converter in pic16f877

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, pic-ccs

I am using pic16f877a adc converter with ccs compiler and i wish to vary my reference voltages, vref+ and vref-. How do i do this?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: It would be nice if you could expand your post and give more details.

Comment: Closing this mess.  I can't guess whether "vary my reference voltage" means you want to control something outside that changes the voltage, or you want to switch what is being used as the reference inside the PIC.  I might have given you some slack to respond before closing, but the overall sloppiness, and thereby disrespect, exhibited by your question gives me a *screw this* attitude.  If you don't care about your problem, why should we?

Comment: @stephen Please have respect for other users on this site and write questions that communicate clearly. Include as much information as possible, paragraphs instead of sentences. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In addition to writing directly to the configuration register, the CCS compiler for PICs has a library function `setup_adc_ports()` that can select a reference.  For example, if I wanted to have analog inputs A0 and A1, and low reference A2 and high reference A3, I could make this call:

```
setup_adc_ports(AN0_AN1_VREF_VREF); // A0 A1 VRefh=A3 VRefl=A2
```

You can find the constants for the `setup_adc_ports()` in the `<16F877.h>` header file that comes with the CCS compiler.

Answer (score 0):

(The PIC16F877A is a little old, not recommended for new designs, but if its what you've got then that's fine).

The ADC can either take the supply rails as the reference, or you can provide another voltage reference externally on Vref+ and Vref- pins.

Which reference you use is controlled by the PFCG pins of the ADCON1 register (see page 128 of the datasheet).

Do you already have some code for setting ADCON1?

e.g. ADCON1 = 0x08;     would use an external voltage reference

```
 ADCON1 = 0x00;     would use the voltage rails
```

(I don't use the CCS compiler so defined name might be diffferent from ADCON1